# is hp envy 15 2020 model compatible with linux distros?

Tags: release-loki, release-freya, release-hera, system-installation, system

I would like to know whether HP Envy 15 2020 model is compatible with linux distros or not?
I am going to buy one of these new products, to be more specific the HP Envy 15 ep0123tx.
I have read many reviews regard this issue and it looks that there are some screen issues, only half of the screen is displayed.
Anyone has any experience of installing linux on these new laptops please share your ideas.
thank you.

Comment: Nobody here will know this question unless they have that exact model. The answer is probably, **"Yes, though you may need to futz about getting drivers to work."** That's true with most every device out there. Before you install, boot to a live USB and test the device's hardware. If the hardware doesn't work properly, try a different distro - one with a newer kernel for example. The chances of someone here having that exact model are pretty low - this is a fairly low-traffic site.

Answer (score 0):

[This query](https://linux-hardware.org/?view=computers&year=2020&type=Notebook&vendor=Hewlett-Packard&model=ENVY+Laptop+15-ep0xxx) on https://linux-hardware.org shows that some people have been able to get Linux working on that specific model.
You might check the individual hardware probes for any particular hardware issues.
Since at least one probe is Ubuntu 20.04, it's likely the device will work with elementaryOS even if this requires the newer kernel in 20.04 since Ubuntu backports Linux kernels through its hardware-enablement stack to older LTS releases, i.e. Ubuntu 18.04 which elementaryOS 5 is based-on.

Comment: thank you for sharing your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Successfully tried Pop OS 20.04 LTS (With Nvidia driver) on HP Envy 15 ep0123tx. Also Fedora 34 Workstation with compiling Nvidia graphics driver after installation. Instruction available on internet. Works, but not without some glitches.

1. Finger print sensor is not recognized rest everything works.
2. Do not save the X config generated by the Nvidia settings utility. The built-in display goes blank after boot. The Nvidia card takes over the primary display port. 3.There are issues in remembering the external monitor setup profile. Things like orientation will be lost across reboots.
3. Generally, I found that video playback is disturbingly choppy.

Maybe there are workarounds for these problems. But I went back to my previous setup. Windows 10 host and Linux as guest on Virtualbox.